# How to parse text json in linq with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, json, postgresql, entity-framework, linq

I have a table `SliceStatements` (DB: PostgreSQL) that has a column `Payload`. The column's datatype is `String` but the string is in json format. The json has field `rows` which is an array of objects. It is known that each objects has field `locationM`.

I need to write a Linq query to get first 1000 rows of JSON objects (not `SliceStatements`), ordered by `locationM`.

I know that I can do it easily by loading data first using `AsEnumerable` or something like that, but there is so much data that application crashes with `OutOfMemoryException`.

So how do I write the linq query?

Here's my code:

```
await _context.SliceStatements.AsNoTracking()
            .SelectMany(s => (JArray)JObject.Parse(s.Payload)["rows"], (s, row) => new { row })
            .OrderBy(r => r["locationM"])
            .Take(1000)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Sadly, I get

> The LINQ expression 's => (JArray)JObject.Parse(s.Payload).get_Item("rows")' could not be translated.

I know I can parse text into JSON using SQL query by `fieldName::json`, but I don't know how to do it using linq.

And I would like to not write whole query as SQL, cause my code is 10% of the whole query, that consists of multiple Join and Where.

Comment: I think your table should be  improved. You need to create a separate column  LocationM and each time whent you save a json string, you will have to save LocationM from the json too. It will significantly improve the performance.

Comment: @Serge I would like it to be different but it will actually require A LOT of refactoring (since LocationM is just one of the needed columns) and I'm not in charge in the team for such decision.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [doc](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html?tabs=data-annotations%2Cpoco) describing how to work with Postgres's Json coulmns using EF Core. Looks like you need to add the `[Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]` attribute to your `Payload` column containing JSON. After that, it is easy to query using Linq in a normal way.

There should be something like this (it is just a sort of pseudocode, I did not run it):

```
_context
.SliceStatements
.AsNoTracking()
.SelectMany(x => x.Payload.rows)
.OrderBy(x => x.locationM);
```